# how to delete reserved URL in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

how to delete reserved URL in Powershell?

I am attempting to delete all the reserved reporting related URLs by using powershell because Report Server Webservice is not properly configured and I need to reset from the start.

However I can't able to complete it. Help me check the errors tell me how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### How to delete a reserved URL using `netsh`

You are not using Powershell, you are using `netsh` in a `cmd` shell.

In addition, the syntax of your command is incorrect.

There needs to be an `url=` before `http...`:

```
F:\test>netsh http delete urlacl /?

Usage: delete urlacl [url=]<string>

Parameters:

    Tag     Value
    url  -  The fully qualified URL to be deleted.

Remarks: This command deletes a reserved URL.

Examples:

         delete urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri
         delete urlacl url=http://www.contoso.com:80/MyUri
```